# /usr/local/lib: file not recognized: Is a directory

Tags: centos6, justniffer

When installing justniffer on CentOS 6.5,

```
./configure
```

works fine, but `make` gives the following error:

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o justniffer justniffer-main.o justniffer-formatter.o justniffer-utilities.o justniffer-regex.o justniffer-prog_read_file.o /usr/local/lib  -L/root/justniffer/lib/libnids-1.21_patched/src -lnids2 -lpcap -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_program_options -lpython2.6
/usr/local/lib: file not recognized: Is a directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [justniffer] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/justniffer/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

What's the solution for this?

Comment: justniffer at [https://github.com/onotelli/justniffer](https://github.com/onotelli/justniffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use`./configure LIBS="-I /usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib"` ,then `make`,it's work!

Comment: I was missing the `-L` before library path

Answer (score 0):

Having not compile program for so long time, made the same silly mistake:

- Like `CFLAGS`, `LIBS`, `GTK_LIBS` etc should be flags e.g. `-Lpath`, not bare paths. What I used to do is relocate all DIRs to CFLAGS=/I/L Another way to
- Spaces should be quoted or escaped like `LIBS="-L'c/program files/gtk+/lib'"`
  `LIBS="-Lc/program\ files/gtk+/lib"`

Answer (score -1):

vi Makefile and src/Makefile

`LIBS = -pthread -lm -lz -ldl -lutil`

make & make install

Success!

Comment: English is required on Stack Overflow. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content